# pandas dataframe find NaN explicitly

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a dataframe that can potentially contain NaN values.  How do I find the NaNs and only the NaNs?  Most suggestions suggest using df.isnull, but this returns None values as well.  I only care about NaN.

Thanks

Comment: Somewhat-broadly, you may find a big advantages removing the native Python None from your array if you can (perhaps you are)! Perhaps filtering them as a new boolean column.

Answer (score 1):

To find `NAN` values you can use:

```
df.isna().sum(axis='index') # or axis = 0
df.isna().sum(axis='columns') # or axis = 1 
df.isna().sum().sum() # to find all nan values in df
```

`NOTE`: `df.isna()` will return a df(shape same as original df) with boolean values. Then you can use above 3 functions to evaluate `nan` values.

`TO COUNT ONLY NAN's`:

You can replace `None` with `random_str`, and then evaluate the `NaN` Count.

```
new_df = df.astype(str).replace('None','Random_str')
```

Comment: So [df.isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html#pandas-dataframe-isna) "Return a boolean same-sized object indicating if the values are NA. **NA values, such as None or numpy.NaN, gets mapped to True values.** Everything else gets mapped to False values." Additionally `isnull` is an "**Alias of isna.**" so this is an identical solution to the thing that is not working in OP's question.